# Two frameworks jQuery and Prototype on a project.

Tags: jquery, frameworks, prototype

Currently supporting a project that includes both frameworks...

Hence having a question for these ones who had experience with both:

1. Any pros and cons of having both frameworks, for example what jQuery can't do that Prototype can?
2. Method override? Would I get into the situation where I get one method calling both frameworks :)
3. Suggestions

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Pros: You like to do it that way and have both frameworks.  Cons:
   Two frameworks, so more for one client javascript thread to do
2. Jquery uses $ or jQuery, Prototype uses Prototype - shouldn't get
   into trouble - unless you try to mix those objects or something.
3. Use just one framework unless you have a very, very special reason to use both. I'd probably go with jQuery only - though your choice.